# Cross-browser support for not loading images - responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, cross-browser

I want to use image_1 for desktop screens and image_2 for mobile as background images, and of course I don't want to load image_1 when the mobile version is in use(image_2 is loaded). Is this possible with css-only  and cross-browser support(including old browsers)?

I came out with this solution, but I don't know if this is cross-browser(with IE10/edge and latest version of FF, opera, chrome - it's working fine).

**HTML**

```
<div class="bg">
   <div>
      <div>
         Content
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bg {
      background: #FFFFFF url("image_1.png") no-repeat center top;
}

@media (max-width:306px) {
   .bg {
      background: #FFFFFF url("image_2.png") no-repeat center top; 
                           /* will the image_1.png image load this way
                           in old browsers if condition of max-width is true?*/
   }
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem? If you aren't sure if it works in some browsers, then test it in those browsers.

Comment: To test each version of each browser? N-ice solution!

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine in all browsers except ie8 and below which do not support media queries

Comment: I know about ''should'', I just don't know if it is

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this for you and this will work will all browsers except earlier versions of IE which do not support media queries.

:)

Comment: How did you tested it? :) Is there any caniuse-like method or alike?  Thanks anyway :)

Comment: But this doesn't provide any tool to detect if the image_1 is loaded(by it's weight - size). I'm not talking here about visual aspect only...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean when you have a media query like yours when the screen reaches above 306px then it will start to use the image_1.png you have set up. you have not specified anything for weight size etc.